# How to hide the loaded datepicker using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, datepicker

This is my datepicker:

```
<input type="text" name="offerdate" class="datecls" style="width:62px;" id="date_1" onclick="return check_group_name('date_1');"/>
```

This is the script:

```
function check_group_name(dateid) {
        var groupmodelGrpname = $("#groupmodelGrpname").val();
        if(groupmodelGrpname == ""){
            alert("Select Group Before Selecting Offer Date");
            $("#groupmodelGrpname").focus();
            $("#dateid").val("");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

In my form there have a dropdown box.So I need to check this drop down seleceted before selecting value from datepicker.

That means if i click on datepicker first will check, the drop down have any selected value .If it have not then alert the `"Select Group Before Selecting Offer Date"`.

This is working perfectly ,but there have some issu.

When i clicked on the date picker the alert will come, but the loaded calender not disappearing.

I need to display the calender when there have no alerts means that only alert will come if the drop down have value.

How can i do this?

Comment: $('#dateid').datepicker("hide");
this did not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function check_group_name(dateid) {
    var groupmodelGrpname = $("#groupmodelGrpname").val();
    if(groupmodelGrpname == ""){
        alert("Select Group Before Selecting Offer Date");
        $("#groupmodelGrpname").focus();
        $("#dateid").val("");
        $('#dateid').datepicker("hide"); 
        return false;
    }
}
```